# Image Files are not Stored with Specified Dimensions in R

Tags: r, macos, image, file, png

So I am trying to save images as files. For instance, like this:

```
 
  png("image.png", units = "in", res = 500, width = 35, 
      height = 35, pointsize = 40)
  
  plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
  
  dev.off()
```

I am expecting a PNG image file of dimension 35 X 35 inches with resolution 500 pixels/inch. However, when inspecting the image file with finder on MAC, the image file turns out to be of size 243.06 X 243.06 inches and 72 pixels per inch.

This is the information I get when opening the image with `Preview` and choosing `tools` and `adjust size`.

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: @user2554330 I don't think I quite understand. Seems to me like the image I got is way bigger and also of much lower quality than I asked for.

Comment: The number of pixels (which is the quality) is identical. Set the resolution in Preview to 500 to match the resolution at which you saved it.

Comment: (I'd note that 300 dpi is fairly standard for "high resolution"--photos at 300 dpi print nicely. Going higher than that increases your file size without any noticeable increase in visual quality.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relatively new-ish [`ragg` package](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg) provides nicely modern graphic devices that are more efficient and higher quality than the default graphics devices--and apparently it does a better job encoding the resolution into the the file so your viewers will default to the resolution you want.

Comparing these two files:

```
png("sample_png.png", units = "in", res = 500, width = 35, 
      height = 35, pointsize = 40)
  
plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
  
dev.off()

 
library(ragg) 
agg_png(
  filename = "sample_agg.png",
  units = "in", res = 500, width = 35, 
  height = 35, pointsize = 40
)

plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
  
dev.off()
```

The `ragg` PNG defaults to 500 dpi when opened in Preview, and the ragg file is also 1.6 MB compared to 6.2 MB with `png()`.

Comment: This package seems to work well. However I'm beginning to think saving the images as PDF would be better. The quality seems to be just as good, and the files take up a lot less space. Also, that way you don't have to worry about choosing the width and height correctly in accordance with the resolution like you do with PNG for instance.

Comment: Be a little careful with PDF--the file size will scale with the number of elements rather than the number of pixels (because there are no pixels...). If you have a scatterplot of 10,000 points, a PNG will have a much smaller file size than a PDF. But as PDF uses vector graphics, the resolution is essentially unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code, and I don't see what you describe.  The `image.png` file information shows dimensions `17500 × 17500`, which are the dimensions in pixels corresponding to 35in x 35in at 500 pixels per inch.  The image resolution is not shown.  (I don't know if it is saved in the file; that's possible, but the Finder isn't showing it to me.)

So I think whatever method you used to determine the dimensions of the file are wrong, not the file itself.

Comment: I made an edit to my post. You are correct that the image is `17500 x 17500` pixels, but the resolution is 72 pixels per inch, meaning the actual size of the image is `243.06 x 243.06` inches. You can check the DPI for instance by opening the image in ´Finder` and choosing `tools` and `show inspector`.